# How to find the total number of ways one can reach (5,5) from (0,0)

Tags: catalan-numbers

The total number of ways one can reach $(5,5)$ from $(0,0)$ is $^{10}C_5$ as per a tutorial I am following. I know there are $5$ rights and $5$ ups. So there are 10 steps. But why it is choose $5.$

Comment: A path from $(0,0)$ to $(5,5)$ will look something like $RRUURUURRU$ i.e. it will have five $R'$s and five $U'$s. So once we choose five spots for one type then the other five spots automatically will have to be of the other type.

Comment: This way to visualize helped me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 10 steps, and you choose 5 of them to be rights.